# Creating controllers for custom tiles attributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-roo

As we all know, we could create any controllers on spring/spring-roo and it would be displayed in the `body` tile attribute on every layout.jspx we create/customize.

Is it possible to create controllers that can be display on any tile attribute name? I was planning to record statistics on menu clicks. Javascript was an option but could it be done via spring/spring-roo?

Comment: What do you mean by "can be display on any tile attribute name"? - I know hat a "tile" is, as well what a "tile attribute name" is, but I do not know what you mean by DISPLAY on a TILE ATTRIBUTE NAME.

Comment: Definition of tile is correct. To display on a tile attribute name is like having every created controller and view to be displayed on the `body` tile attribute. But what I was hoping is it would be possible to display the created controller and view on any tile attribute (ie., `menu`, `footer`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I did not use tiles for some time, but as far as i can remember in the template definitions you a mapping pathnames to jsp. Did you try to call a controller insted of a jsp (psudo code, header section):

```
<definition name="myapp.homepage" template="/layouts/classic.jsp">
  <put-attribute name="header" value="/do/something/special/" />
  <put-attribute name="body" value="/tiles/home_body.jsp" />
   ...
</definition>

@Controller
public class StatisticsController {

    @RequestMapping("/do/something/special/") 
    public void someAction {
    ...
    }    
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've tried so far I can't display any menu,sec JSTL. I was planning to move the code from `WEB-INF/views/menu.jspx` to `[do/something/special]/menu.jspx`. Am I doing it wrong?